# SQL Server 2008 - Display time difference

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have SQL Server 2008 query that displays `Start_of_Attack` and `End_of_Attack`:

```
SELECT
    CAST (DATEADD(SECOND, dbo.AGENT_SECURITY_LOG_1.BEGIN_TIME /1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101') AS VARCHAR(50)) as Start_of_Attack,
    CAST (DATEADD(SECOND, dbo.AGENT_SECURITY_LOG_1.END_TIME /1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101') AS VARCHAR(50)) as End_of_Attack
FROM
    dbo.AGENT_SECURITY_LOG_1
WHERE
    dbo.AGENT_SECURITY_LOG_1.TIME_STAMP > DATEDIFF(second, '19700101', DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()))  * CAST(1000 as bigint)
```

I would like to display a third column, `Duration_of_Attack`

How do I display the time difference between `Start_of_Attack` and `End_of_Attack` ?

Comment: Try `DATEDIFF(ss, BEGIN_TIME, END_TIME)`, this should give you duration in seconds.

Comment: Any reason you're not storing your datetime as a `DATETIME`?

Comment: @GoatCO --- I don't know how to store datetime as DATETIME, will google it ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're storing your date as an integer, you can just do:

```
SELECT (dbo.AGENT_SECURITY_LOG_1.END_TIME 
     - dbo.AGENT_SECURITY_LOG_1.BEGIN_TIME )/1000 as Duration_Of_Attack
```

If the values were stored as `DATETIME` you could use `DATEDIFF()` easily, as it is you can still use `DATEDIFF()` but it requires casting your existing date as `DATETIME()` instead of `VARCHAR()` and is needless:

```
SELECT
    CAST (DATEADD(SECOND, dbo.AGENT_SECURITY_LOG_1.BEGIN_TIME /1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101') AS VARCHAR(50)) as Start_of_Attack,
    CAST (DATEADD(SECOND, dbo.AGENT_SECURITY_LOG_1.END_TIME /1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101') AS VARCHAR(50)) as End_of_Attack,
    DATEDIFF(ss,CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, dbo.AGENT_SECURITY_LOG_1.BEGIN_TIME /1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101') AS DATETIME)
               ,CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, dbo.AGENT_SECURITY_LOG_1.END_TIME /1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101') AS DATETIME))   
FROM
    dbo.AGENT_SECURITY_LOG_1
WHERE
    dbo.AGENT_SECURITY_LOG_1.TIME_STAMP > DATEDIFF(second, '19700101', DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()))  * CAST(1000 as bigint)
```

It's advisable to use one of the appropriate `DATETIME` data types, but you've got another 22 years or so before you'll run into problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [DATEDIFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258269%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

`DATEDIFF(ss, BEGIN_TIME, END_TIME)`, should give you duration in seconds.

**EDIT:** As per the OP the `BEGIN_TIME` and `END_TIME` are not of SQL Server DATETIME type.
 They are saved in milli seconds, so Gordon's solution of just finding the difference of the 2 columns and converting that to seconds should work.

Comment: I tried and get error "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime."

Comment: @Glowie I was assuming that the columns were of `DATETIME` type, if not just divide by 1000 as Gordon mentioned, his solution should work. I will update my answer with that info.

Answer (score 2):

Your times look like they are in a Unix format of milliseconds since a reference time.  So just take the difference:

```
SELECT (dbo.AGENT_SECURITY_LOG_1.END_TIME - dbo.AGENT_SECURITY_LOG_1.END_TIME) / 1000 as diff_in_seconds
```